# With Ubuntu 12.04 unlike 11.04 Wine installed application start menu links are missing

Tags: ubuntu, wine, dash

With Ubuntu 12.04 and wine 1.4 unlike ubuntu 11.04 with wine 1.2.2 installed application start menu links are missing.

For instance with Ubuntu 11.04 including Wine I can install one of our Windows applications and then can go to Applications > Wine > Programs > Semantic Designs > TestCoverage > Documentation to bring up the documentation for how to run our tool.

Unfortunately with Ubuntu 12.04  the Applications menu is gone and going to Dash I do see "Recent Apps and more apps" but my installed Wine application and related documentation link is NOT shown present, even though the wine uninstaller shows it present.

I found this online suggestion and tried using the gnome "main menu"...

Windows key to launch the Dash.
  Enter "Main Menu" in the search field and open the old Edit Main Menu app.
  Select the Category (aka Unity Dash Filter) you want the item in.
  Name the Dash/Launcher Item
  Add the Command to launch said app

With "mainmenu" then get down to the TestCoverage > Documentation and I could see a command link in properties of ..

env WINEPREFIX="/home/sdtest/.wine" wine C:\windows\command\start.exe /Unix /home/sdtest/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/sdtest/Start\ Menu/Programs/Semantic\ Designs/Test\ Coverage/Java\ 1.7\ Documentation.lnk

BUT I could not execute this link to view the installed documentation.
So I copied the link properties into a file, set it as executable, and ran it as a bash script and the documentation came up!

So why can't I use this link under main menu?